# Bash Shell script extract Json object

Tags: json, bash, shell, awk, grep

In Bash shell script, I want to extract an object. For example, with following json file, I would like to extract `dependencies` object and it should return me: `"dmg": ">= 0.0.0", "build-essential": ">= 0.0.0", "windows": ">= 0.0.0"` in whatever format and how do you do that?

// My data 1.json:

```
{
    "platforms": {
        "amazon": ">= 0.0.0",
        "arch": ">= 0.0.0",
        "centos": ">= 0.0.0",
        "debian": ">= 0.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "dmg": ">= 0.0.0",
        "build-essential": ">= 0.0.0",
        "windows": ">= 0.0.0"
    },
    "recommendations": {}
}
```

// My data 2.json:

```
{
    "platforms": {
        "amazon": ">= 0.0.0",
        "arch": ">= 0.0.0",
        "centos": ">= 0.0.0",
        "debian": ">= 0.0.0"
    },
    "recommendations": {},
    "dependencies": {
        "dmg": ">= 0.0.0",
        "build-essential": ">= 0.0.0",
        "windows": ">= 0.0.0"
    }
}
```

// My data 3.json:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "dmg": ">= 0.0.0",
        "build-essential": ">= 0.0.0",
        "windows": ">= 0.0.0"
    },
    "platforms": {
        "amazon": ">= 0.0.0",
        "arch": ">= 0.0.0",
        "centos": ">= 0.0.0",
        "debian": ">= 0.0.0"
    },
    "recommendations": {}
}
```

// My data 4.json:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "dmg": ">= 0.0.0",
        "build-essential": ">= 0.0.0",
        "windows": ">= 0.0.0"
    }
}
```

// My data 5.json (compress):

```
{"dependencies":{"dmg":">= 0.0.0","build-essential":">= 0.0.0","windows":">= 0.0.0"},"platforms":{"amazon":">= 0.0.0","arch":">= 0.0.0","centos":">= 0.0.0","debian":">= 0.0.0"},"recommendations":{}}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
sed -n '/dependencies/, /}/ p' t|grep '>='
```

---

**How this works :**

First get the text between `dependencies` block, and then extract the dependencies.

*Note that this method is independent of **where** in the text the dependency block is located. 
As long as it is present, you'll get the answer.*

---

```
aman@apollo:~$ sed -n '/dependencies/, /\}/ p' t|grep '>='
        "dmg": ">= 0.0.0",
        "build-essential": ">= 0.0.0",
        "windows": ">= 0.0.0"
```

---

Use `sed -n '/dependencies/, /}/ p' t|grep '.*='`

If there can be symbols like `~=`, `=` in the dependency block (and not just `>=`).

---

**Compressed version**
For the compressed version, you can first "decompress" (insert newlines) the file and then apply the same transformation.

```
sed -e 's/:{/:{\n/g'  -e  's/},/\n},\n/g' d5|sed -n '/dependencies/, /}/ p'|grep '>='
```

The original solution will work for all the 4 other files.

Comment: would be safer this way? sed -n '/dependencies/, /}/ p' metadata.json | grep -v "[{}]"

Comment: do you know the answer for this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316714/bash-shell-extract-object-from-json-file

Comment: How is sed reading the file here?  makes no sense to me.

Comment: Bad filenames perhaps (`t`, `d5`).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [jsawk](https://github.com/micha/jsawk)? I would generally use python for parsing JSON data on UNIX systems, since it usually comes bundled with the OS.

Anyways, you can try this:

```
awk "/dependencies/,/}/ { print }" test.json | grep ":" | grep -v dependencies
```

in general, to get text between two patterns/strings:

```
awk "/Pattern1/,/Pattern2/ { print }" inputFile
```

and then use grep ":" to get all the lines containing the ':' in the object, and then filter out the object name itself by getting all the subsequent lines not containing the object name

UPDATE: 
for json not in pretty format

```
sed "s/[,{}]/&\n/g" prettified.json | awk "/dependencies/,/}/ { print }" | grep ":" | grep -v dependencies | awk '{$1=$1}1'
```

Comment: this might be a problem if json file is not pretty format, for example json file is compressed into one single line. Any thought?

Comment: Updated the regex, now should work for both pretty and ugly formats lol

Comment: Doesn't work if its a string coming in from a curl response.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way with `awk`:

```
awk -v RS= -F'},|{' '{print $5}' file | awk 'NF'
```

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'},|{' '{print $5}' f | awk 'NF'
    "dmg": ">= 0.0.0",
    "build-essential": ">= 0.0.0",
    "windows": ">= 0.0.0"
```

Comment: I'm curious, how does it know the block named "dependencies" to extract? I don't see the keyword "dependencies" in your command.

Comment: @NamNguyen I set the input to paragraph mode `RS=` and the field separator to `},` or `{`. Once the file is split I just pick the field you seek by stating the `$5`. That is the field holding value you need. The last pipe is to remove blank lines.

Comment: it's very sort and I'm having hard time to understand your solution. I'm still reading your commend and learn from pro :) . Kinna like your solution :)

Comment: @NamNguyen Thanks `:)`. It's pretty simple. Just look at your input and count the fields by splitting them at every `},` or `{`. You'll see your block is the `5th` field.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ $ tr -d '\n' < myjson.json | sed -e's/[}{]//g' | sed -e's/.*dependencies\":\(.*\)\s*,.*/\1/g' | sed -e's/^ *//g' | sed -e's/, */, /g'
"dmg": ">= 0.0.0", "build-essential": ">= 0.0.0", "windows": ">= 0.0.0"
```

Comment: look like this solution does not work well for some of my cases.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know about your cases :)

Comment: for example, my case is json file is compressed such as all in one line. But I still appreciate for your input.

Comment: that's what the `tr -d '\n' < myjson.json` does.

Comment: for example, this would fail for this test case: {
    "b": {
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "dmg": ">= 0.0.0",
        "build-essential": ">= 0.0.0",
        "windows": ">= 0.0.0"
    },
    "a": {
    }
}

Comment: I could not give all the cases in here so I created gist and this gist is the real file that would not work for your case. https://gist.github.com/gdbtek/9303222 Almost :)

Comment: If there are going to be many unexpected cases you probably want to look into `jsawk` or using python of perl instead of shell.