# Extract JSON object using Bash shell?

Tags: json, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have a following json file and I'm looking for a way to extract object using object path using bash shell.

For example, if I say `extract('production-ap/ap-northeast-1')`, then it will return me `"accessKey": "OO"`, `"accountID": "99"`.

I like bash shell scripting but have limited knowledge of it, please help!

Thanks

```
{
    "production-ap": {
        "ap-northeast-1": {
            "accessKey": "OO",
            "accountID": "99"
        },
        "ap-northeast-2": {
            "accessKey": "AB",
            "accountID": "12"
        }
    },
    "production-eu": {
        "eu-west-1": {
            "accessKey": "CD",
            "accountID": "34"
        },
        "us-east-1": {
            "accessKey": "CD",
            "accountID": "34"
        }
    },
    "production-us": {
        "us-east-1": {
            "accessKey": "EF",
            "accountID": "56"
        },
        "us-east-2": {
            "accessKey": "EF",
            "accountID": "56"
        }
    },
    "stage-ap": {
        "ap-northeast-1": {
            "accessKey": "AK",
            "accountID": "78"
        },
        "ap-northeast-2": {
            "accessKey": "AK",
            "accountID": "78"
        }
    },
    "stage-eu": {
        "eu-west-1": {
            "accessKey": "AK",
            "accountID": "55"
        },
        "eu-west-2": {
            "accessKey": "AK",
            "accountID": "55"
        }
    },
    "stage-us": {
        "us-east-1": {
            "accessKey": "AK",
            "accountID": "30"
        },
        "us-east-2": {
            "accessKey": "AK",
            "accountID": "30"
        }
    },
    "private": {
        "us-west-2": {
            "accessKey": "z2",
            "accountID": "52"
        },
        "us-west-1": {
            "accessKey": "z2",
            "accountID": "52"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-sed-and-awk

Comment: @atupal, they all use python,... third party lib which my project requires no dependencies except bash shell

Comment: No, the [jsawk](https://github.com/micha/jsawk) uses only bash.

Comment: `Jq` would be helpful http://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's going to be flaky doing this using bash. There [do seem to be](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSON.sh) json parsers written as shell scripts although I'm not sure how solid they are. I'd recommend something like [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) which can run as a separate program and be used in a pipe. It's a standalone executable and written in C. There's no reason it can't be shipped along with your program.

Comment: look like JSON.sh you suggested works as expected. I'm testing it more.

Comment: I took JSON.sh as the solution. It works very well. Thanks